# Modify Javascript Array Element

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array element of the following format (with one whitespace character between each pair of letters, ignore the quote marks which are not part of the actual element):

```
arr[1] = "AB CD EF GH"
```

How can I edit this to be of the following format (with each pair of letters surrounded by * and two spaces between each pair of letters):

```
arr[1] = "*AB*  *CD*  *EF*  *GH*"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split`, `map`, then `join`:

```
arr[1] = arr[1].split(' ').map(function (el) {
  return '*' + el + '*';
}).join('  ');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cLstj4Lt/)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the single space:

```
arr[1] = "*" + arr[1].replace(/ /g, "*  *") + "*";

alert(arr[1]);
```