# How to add something in existing element of an array?

Tags: javascript

To be specific:
Let consider this array -

```
var strings = ['John', 'Jane', 'Mary'];
```

Now the question is how can I add something to that existing element in array like I want to append `|Teacher` in `John` so that it would be `John|Teacher`.

So altogether, I want is -

```
var strings = ['John|Teacher', 'Jane|Doctor', 'Mary|Housekeeper'];
```

How can I do this? Please help.

Comment: Iterate over the array and append |Teacher to every element. Use a `for` loop or the `Array.map` function to iterate over elements.

Comment: Get the content of the array at index `i`, modify the string, store the value back at index `i`

Comment: The question is unclear. When do you want to add `Teacher`, `Doctor`, `Housekeeper` ?

Comment: sounds like you would be better off with a different model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify Javascript Array Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924905/modify-javascript-array-element)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var strings1 = ['John', 'Jane', 'Mary'];
var strings2 = ['Teacher', 'Doctor', 'Housekeeper'];
var strings = strings1.map(function(e, i) {return e + '|' + strings2[i];});
```

Comment: Awesome. Also did it with forEach! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are you returning an Array from the map callback?

Comment: @llama: Returning the array that this dude was asking for.

Comment: @goodvibration: Where? Looks to me like the result should be an array of strings, not an array of arrays that have a single string. His result: `['John|Teacher', 'Jane|Doctor', 'Mary|Housekeeper'];` Your result: `[['John|Teacher'], ['Jane|Doctor'], ['Mary|Housekeeper']];`

Comment: @llama: Oh well, I just "alerted" the results, so probably missed that. You can simply remove the `[` and `]` (which I just did myself).

Comment: @llama Good eye there. But fixed it :)